# Phpstorm + jade настройка Code style

Tags: phpstorm, jade

не могу понять почему в phpstrorm не подсвечивается синтаксис jade файла и не работает автодополнеение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что именно не работает? По Вашей картинке судя, синтаксическая подсветка есть... а автодополнение и не должно работать в Code Style preview.

Comment: не работает подсветка синтаксиса в файле jade и как сделать тогда автодополнение?

Comment: понятнее не стало, простите:( Вы просто повторили исходный текст. Хотелось бы поподробнее. Скриншот собственно файла вместо preview из настроек форматтера, и скриншоты, показывающие, как именно и где Вы пытаетесь вызвать completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас расширение `*.jade` ассоциировано с типом файлов DTD (XML Document Type Definition); откройте Settings | Editor | File Types, уберите `jade` из списка DTD паттернов и добавьте его в Jade registered patterns

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, заработало